# Why the font color setting button does not shown in Ckeditor4 Tool bar?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor4.x

I want the editor to let the user change the editor's content text colour.

Here is my code:

```
import { CKEditor } from 'ckeditor4-react';
export default function Editor() {

let config={
    toolbar: [
        [ 'Source' ],
        [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ],
        [ 'Bold', 'Italic' ],
        [ 'Undo', 'Redo' ],
        ['TextColor', 'BGColor'],
        [ 'About' ]
    ],
    extraPlugins: 'easyimage',
    removePlugins: 'image',
    cloudServices_uploadUrl: 'https://33333.cke-cs.com/easyimage/upload/',
    cloudServices_tokenUrl:
        'https://33333.cke-cs.com/token/dev/ijrDsqFix838Gh3wGO3F77FSW94BwcLXprJ4APSp3XQ26xsUHTi0jcb1hoBt'
}
let hello=()=>{
    console.log("hoi");
}

return (
    <CKEditor
        config={config}
        initData="<p>Hello from CKEditor 4!</p>"
        onBlur={hello}
        onInstanceReady={() => {
            console.log('Editor is ready!');
        }}
    />
)
}
```

However, the font colour setting button does not show in the Ckeditor4 toolbar.

[image]

Would you tell me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
extraPlugins: ['easyimage', 'colorbutton'],
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

What the .....

Just add the following statement to enable the color button.

```
config.extraPlugins = 'colorbutton';
```